# Undocumented Constraint? publishing to topic *from* pubsub trigger

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I don't know if I'm going crazy, or if this is a limitation that just isn't documented (I've scoured the GCP API docs):

Is it possible to have a cloud function with a pubsub trigger on 'topic A', and inside that cloud function, publish a message to 'topic B'.

I've tried all the other triggers with identical code running (cloud functions as HTTP triggers, Cloud Storage Triggers, Firebase Triggers), and they **all successfully publish** to topics.
But the moment I (almost literally) copy-paste my code into a pubsub trigger, after consuming the message, when it attempts to publish it's own message to the next topic, it just **hangs**.  The function just **times-out** when attempting to publish.

So to recap, is the following possible in GCP?

PubSub *Topic A* --> *Cloud Function* --> Pubsub *Topic B*

Thanks in advance for any clarifications!  This is all in Java 11.  Here's the code:

```
...<bunch of imports>

public class SignedURLGenerator implements BackgroundFunction<PubSubMessage> {
  private static final String PROJECT_ID = System.getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT");
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SignedURLGenerator.class.getName());

  /**
  * Handle the incoming PubsubMessage
  **/
 @Override
  public void accept(PubSubMessage message, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String data = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(message.data));
    System.out.println("The input message is: " + data.toString());

    //Do a bunch of other stuff not relevant to the issue at hand...

    publishSignedURL(url.toString());
  }

  //Here's the interesting part
  public static void publishSignedURL(String message) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String topicName = "url-ready-notifier";
    String responseMessage;
    Publisher publisher = null;
    

    try {
      // Create the PubsubMessage object
      ByteString byteStr = ByteString.copyFrom(message, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      PubsubMessage pubsubApiMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(byteStr).build();
      System.out.println("Message Constructed:" + message); 
      //This part works fine, the message gets constructed

      publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicName)).build();
      System.out.println("Publisher Created.");
      //This part also works fine, the publisher gets created

      publisher.publish(pubsubApiMessage).get();
      responseMessage = "Message published.";
      //The code NEVER GETS HERE.  The message is never published.  And eventually the cloud function time's out :(    

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        System.out.println("Something went wrong with publishing: " + e.getMessage());
      }

    System.out.println("Everything wrapped up.");

  }
```

**Edit**
As requested, this is my current POM

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>cloudfunctions</groupId>
      <artifactId>pubsub-function</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
      <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
      </properties>
    
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>libraries-bom</artifactId>
          <version>20.6.0</version>
          <type>pom</type>
          <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
          <artifactId>functions-framework-api</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.1</version>
          <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
          <version>1.117.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-cloud-pubsub</artifactId>
          <version>1.113.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
          <artifactId>gax</artifactId>
          <version>1.66.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
          <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
          <version>1.66.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.threeten</groupId>
          <artifactId>threetenbp</artifactId>
          <version>0.7.2</version>
        </dependency>    
      </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to explicitly set the flow control param in your publisher client? like that

```
       publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(ProjectTopicName.of(PROJECT_ID, topicName)).setBatchingSettings(BatchingSettings.newBuilder()
                .setDelayThreshold(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .setElementCountThreshold(1L)
                .setIsEnabled(true)
                .build()).build();
```

I don't know what happens, maybe a default and global configuration of PubSub. If it's not that, I will delete this answer.

---

**EDIT 1**

Here a screen capture of the builder class on a Publisher parent classe

[image]

You have all the default value of the library. However, the behavior that you observe isn't normal. The default must stay the default even if you are in a PubSub trigger. I will open an issue and forward it to the team directly.

Comment: Hey! it worked! that is awesome.  But also very confusing.  Two questions come to mind:
1. Why did this particular code need the flow control params?  why did none of the other triggers need it, in order to publish?

2. What are the default GCP batch sizes?  Before posting this comment, I looked through multiple GCP docs to look at the defaults, but all Google says is "there are defaults", not What the defaults are...any ideas?

Comment: I have shared a screen shot. The class is interesting to understand the underlying mechanism, but what you see on Cloud Functions isn't normal!

Comment: For information: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193263948

Comment: Thanks guillaume, I'll follow that issue and hopefully it gets resolved.  
Also, reading through the javadoc for the Publisher class [https://googleapis.dev/java/gax/latest/com/google/api/gax/batching/BatchingSettings.html?is-external=true] shows that the default Batch Size is 1.

Comment: Can you share your dependency version of function framework and PubSub (or your full pom.xml file). In addition, can you try with the latest version of all libraries? And based on this example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/4a488d7b13f0bf232665e1c6bd90a092610daddf/functions/helloworld/hello-pubsub

Comment: I can't reproduce the case on my side (and the support also!)

Comment: I'll post the POM and will re-try with the latest libraries, first thing tomorrow.

Comment: Hey Guillaume, I've added the POM as an edit to my original post.
I'll try switching the dependency versions to match the ones in your sample project.